# get column from list of dataframes R

Tags: r, list, split, dataframe

I am an R beginner and I am stuck on this problem. I had a dataframe and by using the split() function I have created a list of dataframes, e.g:

```
dfList <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

Now I want to retrieve a column of a specific dataframe, e.g. column 2 from  dataframe 1, so something like

```
dfList[1][2]
```

What I can do right now is create `for` loops to get inside the data structure. But I can't find a oneliner to do it, if it exists. How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `lapply(dfList, '[[', 2)`.  If you need it as a matrix `sapply(dfList, '[[',2)`

Comment: Perhaps you want to use `dfList[[1]][2]`? Here's an example for you to test: `lst <- split(mtcats, mtcars$cyl)` and then `lst[[1]][2]`.

Comment: `lapply(dfList, '[[', 2)` wowza R syntax really is the worst

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm putting docendo's comment here to close out the question.

If you want to extract an element from a list (and treat it like a data.frame) rather than subset a list (to create a smaller list), you need to use the `[[ ]]` syntax. Plus, to get a column by index from a data.frame, you either need to use `[[ idx ]]` or `[, idx ]`. These are pretty basic indexing operations that you will probably want to review if you will be programming in R. So your "correct" call is probably

```
dfList[[1]][[2]]
```